# not able to edit item in the list

Tags: list

I am able to add new item in the list, But not able to edit any item from the list.

I am getting below mentioned error.

**Error 
One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.**

Please assist me, how to resolve this.

Thnaks Gaurav

Comment: have you renamed any column?

Comment: Or developed and added any custom content type?

Comment: Hi Ashish,

yes ashish I have renamed title column name.

Answer (score 0):

have you upgraded the sharepoint recently? 2007 to 2010 or 2010 to 2013?

if so:

goto site settings -> site collection feature -> deactivate "sharepoint server publishing infrastructure"

now in the url goto `http://yoursite/Relationships%20List/allitems.aspx`

delete this list using the ribbon.

now go back to site collection feature and activate "sharepoint server publishing infrastructure"

your list should work!

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19771.sharepoint-2010-one-or-more-field-types-are-not-installed-properly-go-to-the-list-settings-page-to-delete-these-fields.aspx